# I have a JSON.parse syntax error in some wordpress plugin code

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I am new to JSON and struggling with an error in a small section of code.

The code is:

```
this.json = function() {
                return this.text().then(json.parse);
            };
```

The error is:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data
```

Can anyone see what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what the JSON you're trying to parse is. Your code suggests that `this.text()` returns a promise and you want to pipe the text into the `JSON.parse` function. That all looks ok.

Update with the output of `this.text()` and we can see what's invalid in your JSON.

Comment: I am struggling to get any output because of the error. The only way I know it's creating an error is because its showing in the inspect Console. Any suggestions you may have on getting an output would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you replace the code snippet `this.text().then(json.parse)` with `this.text().then(console.log)`? That should output the JSON into the console.

Comment: That didn't output anything so I assume that the JSON.parse error is being produced elsewhere in the wordpress code. Although the error only triggers when this specific plugin is triggered. The plugin is "Usernoise" which is an old feedback plugin (the author doesn't give support anymore) and when I search the plugin code it only has one instance of JSON.parse

Comment: Yeah, without the actual JSON that it's trying to parse I can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: I've delved a bit further and I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing, I looked at the "Network" panel and  a  method=POST, type=json, Cause=fetch, file=https://herefordpetanque.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=un_feedback_get     when I clicked on it it output the following to the browser :

Comment: <style>
   #upg_button, #pure-button {display:none !important;}
  </style>
  {"feedback":[{"id":1332,"status_slug":"in_progress","status":"In progress","title":"Test","time_ago":"2019-10-28T22:04:41+00:00","liked":false,"disliked":false,"likes":0,"comments":0,"avatar":"https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/5ba30e977cbab7e9a988ba78ced823b0?s=96&d=mm&r=g","author":"Frank Sentinella","text":"test"}],"pages":1}

Comment: This matches the feedback notice.  would anything in there trigger the error if it didn't match the json syntax ?

Comment: I also get this in the console :      await fetch("https://herefordpetanque.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=un_feedback_get", { "credentials": "include",
    "headers": { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0", "Accept": "application/json", "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.5", "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8", "Pragma": "no-cache", "Cache-Control": "no-cache" }, "referrer": "https://herefordpetanque.co.uk/", "body": "{\"type\":\"idea\",\"page\":1}", "method": "POST", "mode": "cors"
});

Comment: The network tab records any requests the site makes and allows you to inspect them. It doesn't necessarily mean it has what you're looking for though.


Your second comment has some JSON in there but it would fail if you try to parse the `<style>...</style>` bit. Are you sure that this is what it's trying to parse?